# IOS9: UIScrollView offset in UINavigationController

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

This is beyond frustrating.  I'm having an issue with the UINavigationController (and thus UINavigationBar) pushing my UIScrollView's content down at the top, similar to the issues found here:

[iOS 7 -- navigationController is setting the contentInset and ContentOffset of my UIScrollView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18924431/ios-7-navigationcontroller-is-setting-the-contentinset-and-contentoffset-of-m)

[IOS7 : UIScrollView offset in UINavigationController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18967859/ios7-uiscrollview-offset-in-uinavigationcontroller)

I tried both the recommended solutions of either setting `self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = true` in my view controller's `viewDidLoad()` method and deselecting `Adjust Scroll View Insets` in the Interface Builder.  Both solutions remove the margin at the top, but as a few others have noted, I can't scroll anymore.

The UIScrollView and ContentView fill the entire view controller.  My content view (inside the UIScrollView) contains labels, segments, and a UITextView at the bottom.  Does it have something to do with the content in Content View?

I can attach pictures if needed. Using XCode 7, Swift 2, and iOS 9.

Comment: I solved my issue.  In auto layout, I wasn't setting my content view's height constraint.  I pinned the bottom of the content view to the view controller that contained the UIScrollView.  I removed that pin and explicitly set the height.  It works now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my issue. In auto layout, I wasn't setting my content view's height constraint. 
Previously, I had pinned the bottom of the content view to the view controller that contained the UIScrollView.
I removed that pin and explicitly set the height. It works now.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into the same issue. I had an "About" view with a bunch of labels containing static text. I had a UIScrollView inside of a view controller and it was being pushed down. I had a label pinned to the bottom of the screen that was being drawn off page when it was not necessary to do that.

I had the following view hierarchy:

- View Controller

  - View
  - Scroll View

    - Content View (UIView)
    - Label
    - Label

`Content View` was pinned to the bounds of `Scroll View`, but the width and height had equal constraints to `View`.

I resolved this by adding another `UIView` as a child of `View`. My hierarchy looks like this now:

- View Controller

  - View
  - Inner View (UIView)
  - Scroll View

    - Content View (UIView)
    - Label
    - Label

I set the height constraint on `Content View` to be equal height to `Inner View`. This resolved the issue for me and everything started displaying correctly. `Inner View` is pinned to the borders of `View`.

NOTE: In the hierarchies, the `Label`s should be children of `Content View`. In the preview, it's showing that the Markdown lists can't go that deep.

Answer (score 0):

May or may not apply to you, but if you have a Nav controller and you don't need it to be translucent you can do something along the lines `self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;`

This may help with your odd offsets.

Comment: I gave it a shot, but to no avail.  If I set that property to false, it still pushes the content down, regardless of what `Adjust Scroll View Insets` is set to.