# UICollectionView adds top margin

Tags: ios7, uicollectionview

I want to put a UICollectionView control that shows thumbs horizontally (only a single line of thumbs). For some reason the UICollectionView push the thumbs 44 pixels down, so the "0" height is actually "44". I assume it might be adding this space to consider the navigation bar height (I just assume). Since my UICollectionView is only on part of the screen, I don't want this margin. Is there a way to remove it?

Comment: similar woe ?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24916006/in-a-uicollectionview-the-cells-will-not-sit-on-the-bottom

Answer (score 195, accepted):

The issue may be in collection view's content insets.
Try to add `self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;` into view controller's `viewDidLoad` method.

Comment: Works great. It's very strange this thing cannot be addressed on the storyboard.

Comment: @bashan It can be done on storyboard, there is a checkbox named "Adjust Scroll View Insets"

Comment: I have been working for the same issue since one and half day. I was trying to find the reason. But this worked for me like a charm. Answer really deserves upvotes. Thanks and upvoted !!!

Comment: Note that if you are using an embed segue, and your collection view controller is the embedded controller, you need to call this method to the PARENT controller, and not inside your UICollectionViewController

Comment: i had a tab bar controller added too. I selected by TabBarController in the storyboard and Unchecked ```Under Top Bars``` of ```Extend Edges```. I also unchecked ```Adjust Scroll View Insets``` in both TabBarController and my CollectionView and it worked perfectly

Comment: @RamySabry, https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621372-automaticallyadjustsscrollviewin

Comment: This is deprecated starting iOS 11.

Comment: @VanDuTran did u get relevent ans for iOS 11 ??  also fetching same issue.

Comment: this is the correct answer - regardless if you do it programmatically or via storyboard

Comment: available in iOS 13. But need in iOS 12

Answer (score 87):

You can set this in the storyboard too.

Make sure you've selected the ViewController, and then untick "Adjust Scroll View Insets".

[image]

I haven't tested what this IB/Storyboard method does on iOS6 though. With the code method you need to check that the VC responds to the method:

```
if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(setAutomaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets:)]) {
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;
}
```

Comment: Thanks dude, this save me a loot of time and progress, really saved.

Answer (score 17):

I found that adding:

```
self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
```

In the view controller I was loading the UICollectionView in solved the problem as I couldn't get the accepted answer to work.

The question I found this answer to can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18798792/explaining-difference-between-automaticallyadjustsscrollviewinsets-extendedlayo) and provides an extremely in-depth and interesting explanation of the difference between automatically adjusted scrolled view insets, extended layouts and edge for extended layouts.

Well worth a read

Answer (score 6):

Swift 3:

First you want to set the viewControllers `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets` to false:

```
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
```

Then, you should be able to adjust the edge insets accordingly:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
    //top, left, bottom, right
    return UIEdgeInsets(top: 10, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Maybe you can try to force this value at 0 using the Delegate flow layout of collection view :

```
- (UIEdgeInsets)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout insetForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section
{
    return UIEdgeInsetsMake(PADDING_TOP, PADDING_LEFT, PADDING_BOTTOM, PADDING_RIGHT);
}
```

Modify the value of your padding.

Answer (score 1):

As some others mentioned, `viewController.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets` has been [deprecated since iOS 11](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621372-automaticallyadjustsscrollviewin). My solution...

**Swift 4.2, Xcode 10.1, iOS 12.1:**

For some reason, `collectionView.contentSize.height` was appearing smaller than the resolved height of my collection view. First, I was using an auto-layout constraint relative to 1/2 of the superview's height. **To fix this, I changed the constraint to be relative to the "safe area" of the view.**

This allowed me to set the cell height to vertically fill my collection view using `collectionView.contentSize.height`:

```
private func setCellSize() {
    let height: CGFloat = (collectionView.contentSize.height) / CGFloat(numberOfRows)
    let width: CGFloat = view.frame.width - CGFloat(horizontalCellMargin * 2)

    let layout = collectionView.collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout
    layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: width, height: height)
}
```

**Before**

[image: height relative to superview]
[image: bad collection view layout]

**After**

[image: height relative to safe area]
[image: good collection view layout]

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 5.2 / Xcode 11.3**

```
viewController.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets
```

has been deprecated since iOS 11.

My solution:

```
collectionView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using `self.feedCollectionView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never` on the collection view. This actually worked for me.

Answer (score -3):

Similar to @Sviatoslav answer, you can try the following:

```
- (void) viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];

    yourCollectionView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, 0);
}
```