# UICollectionViewCell Y position locked

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I don't know how this happened, but my UICollectionViewCell somehow moved down from the top, and I can't pull it back up. Also, the Y position in the interface builder is locked at 64, see screenshot.

[image]

Any help would be awesome. Than you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your ViewController, under the attributes inspector, uncheck the "Adjust Scroll View Insets" box.

[image: adjust scroll view insets]

This is also answered in depth here: [UICollectionView adds top margin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19411442/uicollectionview-adds-top-margin)