# UICollectionView scrollview has margin from top and bottom

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

Scroll indicators in `UICollectionView` starts after from some points from top and ends before that many points from bottom. I mean it has top and bottom margin from `UICollectionView`'s top and bottom.

Should not it start from top and end at bottom of `UICollectionView`?

I checked that `contentInset.top` on `UICollectionView` and `sectionInset.top` on `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` are `20.0` and `0.0`, respectively.

See below image. Content start from more than `20.0` pts(which is top inset value) from top.

[image]

Comment: Have you checked `scrollIndicatorInsets`?

Comment: @friedegg-bacon-sandwich It prints `0.0`, too.

Comment: @friedegg-bacon-sandwich Actually it was `64.0`. I was getting `0.0` because I was logging in `viewWillAppear:` method.

Answer (score 4):

I solved by setting value of below properties to `UIEdgeInsetsZero`,

```
// Set contentInset and scrollIndicatorInset to UIEdgeInsetsZero.
self.tournamentCollection.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
self.tournamentCollection.scrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
```

Value of `contentInset.top` and `scrollIndicatorInsets.top` was `64.0`. Similarly for `bottom`. It was causing the contents to start `64.0` pts from top.

Note that you should check above properties' values only after layout pass is executed, otherwise you might get `0.0` as a value. This was the case with me. You should check in `viewDidLayoutSubview:` methods.

Comment: I'm glad you found your solution. Don't forget to mark this as the answer also.

Answer (score 2):

problem in translucent status bar and in your case also nav bar

if your collectionView starts right under nav bar when rendering to it added value to the top of the physical screen (64)

In its Projects I encountered a curious situation.
A nav bar off translucency, but as soon as I hide it in one of the screens, then added to collectionView magic 20 pixels. Yes, yes, this is a translucent status bar
had to take advice Geek

Comment: I gave you a vote because you showed what is causing this mysterious offset to occur in the first place. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Building on @kolbasek's answer, this [other question's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21112952/451735%20%22other%20question's%20answer) shows how to correct it in Storyboard editor ("...select the ViewController, and then untick 'Adjust Scroll View Insets'")