# ios storyboard duplicated CollectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath not called

Tags: ios, storyboard, collectionview

**Things I want to do**

Duplicate a CollectionView From ControllerA to ControllerB in storyboard

**Things I have done**

Duplicate(CMD+D) CollectionView From ControllerA(which works fine)
Drag Drop to ControllerB

retarget(ctrl + drag) dataSource and delegate to ControllerB

**It should be**

duplicated collectionView should work fine like it in ControllerA

**But result is**

`numberOfSectionsInCollectionView` and `numberOfItemsInSection` are called
But `cellForItemAtIndexPath` not called

**Edit 1**

the problem looks like related to the frame size of the CollectionView

CollectionView: size(320,50) flow layout,scroll horizontal

CollectionViewCell: size(50,50)

If I drag CollectionView height to 65,it works with a warning:(`cellForItemAtIndexPath` called)

the behavior of the UICollectionViewFlowLayout is not defined because:
the item height must be less than the height of the UICollectionView minus the section insets top and bottom values.

if CollectionView height >= 114,works without warning.

ControllerA with same parameters size(320,50) will work.don't know why

**Edit 2**

if I duplicate the CollectionView with all same settings and retarget to same delegate. the duplicate one doesn't work as expected. **But** the original one works!! weird!!

Comment: remove your connection again and reconnect, and check your class type which you provided for collection view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After upgrade to xcode 6 beta 5, I notice the cell is not in the visible area of CollectionView

**Solution**:

toggle off `Adjust Scroll View Insets` option in parent view controller attribute inspector
or add this code to parent view controller viewDidLoad method:
`self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;`

ref:[UICollectionView adds top margin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19411442/uicollectionview-adds-top-margin)