# Strange position of modal view

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, modalviewcontroller

I present an UIViewController once by pushing it into a navigationcontroller, and another time by init the root view of a navigation controller.

**FIRST CASE: AS SECOND SLIDE OF A NAVIGATION CONTROLLER**

```
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:riassunto animated:YES];
```

**SECOND CASE: AS ROOT OF MODAL VIEW**

```
   UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:riassunto];

        navigationController.navigationBarHidden     = NO;
        [[navigationController navigationBar] setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlack];
        [self presentViewController:navigationController animated:NO completion:nil];
```

But the position of the view is different:

**FIRST CASE**

[image]

**SECOND CASE**

[image]

It seems that in the second case, modal view, the view does not move down to make room to the top bar. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this in your second view controller:

```
riassunto.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
```

For more info, I'm extending this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/19585104/550034

Comment: It is indeed, by default in iOS7 views fill the whole screen, so you need to tell it that you dont want your view to be resized