# iOS 7 status bar supposed to overlap content?

Tags: ios

I have recently updated my XCode to 5.0.1 as to be able to test my application on iOS 7.

Everything seems to be working as expected, but for some reason the status bar is overlapping the screen's content.

Now, I am still able to see the overlapped content as the status bar in iOS 7 is translucent, but it looks very weird.

I could always move my content down a bit to compensate for the height taken up by the status bar, but how would that look in iOS 6??

Is this intentional on Apple's part? Is there a standard procedure we as developers are supposed to follow to get this looking how it should?

Also, should I just add 20 pixels (or whatever the height of the status bar is) to the top of my view and just forget about iOS 6?

Comment: Wow! Quickest downvote ever, I am amazed!! Swear it took less than 2 seconds after I posted. One of us needs a gold badge for this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Status bar and navigation bar appear over my view's bounds in iOS 7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17074365/status-bar-and-navigation-bar-appear-over-my-views-bounds-in-ios-7)

Comment: Refer to this for a guide of this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18798792/explaining-difference-between-automaticallyadjustsscrollviewinsets-extendedlayo/19585104#19585104

Comment: Too bad I can't downvote my own post, I was thinkin' to myself "if you can't beat 'em, join 'em"

Comment: The site is going downhill with downvoting troll.  Upping your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have decided to just set my `Top Space to: Superview` to 20 (the height of the status bar) for all my parent views.

Looks good on iOS 7 but there is a 20pixel gap on iOS 6, and given the fact that 80% of our iPhone users have already updated their OSes to 7, I think it's safe to just assume that eventually everyone will be using iOS 7 and support for iOS 6 will no longer be needed.

I'm not gonna break my head anymore over this.

Thanks anyways!