# UIViewController refuses to position correctly

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I have a problem with one of my view controllers. Whenever I try to load it, it shows but its bounds are set wrong. Its origin seems to show behind the status bar and I can't seem to make it position bellow the bar.

Here is how I load the uiview in my app window:

```
- (void)loadListOfDevicesViewController:(NSString*)greeting {   
    for (int i = 0; i < [[window subviews] count]; i++) {
        UIView * subView = [[window subviews] objectAtIndex:i];
        [subView removeFromSuperview];
    }

    forceThumbnailRefresh = YES;
    listOfDevicesViewController = [[ListOfDevicesViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ListOfDevicesViewController" bundle:nil];
    listOfDevicesViewController.delegate = self;
    listOfDevicesViewController.bIsForceRefresh = NO;
    listOfDevicesViewController.greetingMessage = greeting;
    [listOfDevicesViewController.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 20, 320.0f, 460.0f)]; //does not seem to work
    [window addSubview:listOfDevicesViewController.view];
}
```

it doesn't seem to take the values that I specify in the frame no matter what.

Can someone help please, all my other view controllers are working perfectly.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Try using this in your view controller:

```
viewController.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
```

I wrote a guide about this here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/19585104/550034

Comment: that did not work for me I'm afraid, Also I'm having the same problem in iOS 6

Answer (score 0):

I found out the problem. It seems in that particular view's XIB file, there was no simulated metrics status bar key.

I added it and now it is working fine which is weird because I thought this was only meant for the simulator and not actual devices