# blank space above the bar?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, ios7

[image]I have a iphone app which is installed in iPad its UI(blank space about 20 pixels above navigation bar) is correctly displayed in ios6 while a blank space appears in ios7 in iPad.
I tried using the default images and using the methods

```
- (void) viewDidLayoutSubviews {

if (([[UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion floatValue] >= 7.0)) {
    CGRect viewBounds = self.view.bounds;
    viewBounds.origin.y = -20;
    self.view.bounds = viewBounds;
}
```

}

but no use.How do i fix it? It is not a universal app.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot (or if your reputation is too low, a link to a screenshot and we can post the image for you)

Comment: added image for reference

Answer (score 0):

The problem is related on the way iOS7 draws the views, please rewfer to these guide to understand the problem:

[Explaining difference between automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets, extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars, edgesForExtendedLayout in iOS7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18798792/explaining-difference-between-automaticallyadjustsscrollviewinsets-extendedlayo/19585104#19585104)