# Buttons appear outside view when placed in TabBarController but not otherwise?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7

Strange problem which I can't seem to reason why it's happening ...

I have designed a simple view controller. Set inside a `UIScrollView`.

[image: Interface Builder view of ScrollView and UIView with content]

When presented outside of the `UITabBarController/NavigationController` all works as it should.

When placed inside a `UITabBarController/NavigationController`, the `UIButton` seems to end up outside of the view of it's container and consequently won't fire any code. And I have absolutely NO idea why.

[image: Picture of "Save Likes" button sitting outside the view and hence not triggering to events]

I have coloured the backgrounds blue and green to show what I mean (now that I can upload photos!)

I can seemingly get the tough stuff working in objective-c without a problem. The easy stuff? Confusing the life out of me. `UITableViews` are still my nemesis and, not far behind, are now `UITabBarController/NavigationController`s.

Does it have something to do with resizing? Auto Layout? Can't see why it works when presented "normally" but, on being inside a `UITabBarController/NavigationController`, things go awry!

Thanks to those who might be able to point me in the right direction!

Comment: it's come status bar issue on your current viewcontroller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:
In Interface Builder go to your view controller and open die property inspector. There, disable "Extend Edges Under Top Bars / Under Bottom Bars".

[image]

Comment: Sadly, I'm doing all this with code. Sigh. Always trying things the hard way! And not using StoryBoards either. Is this possible to be done programmatically? And by that I mean, I'm creating the TabBar Controller etc in code.

Comment: Yes, in your viewDidLoad set the view controller's edgesForExtendedLayout property to UIRectEdgeNone.

Comment: You can also try to set automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets to NO.

Comment: That made things worse :( Made the "blue" region of the view even smaller. Now half the bottom textfield is outside the view rectangle. Sigh.

Comment: Still nothing happening. Either with automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets or edgesForExtendedLayout. But thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Change button's `autoresizingMask` property to `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin` and have a try.

If you are using xib , do like this:

[image]

Comment: @Darren It's impossible to me... Did you try it using code or in xib? If you use the code, where do you add it in?

Answer (score 0):

set your scrollView autosize like below

[image]

Comment: Sadly, this isn't working either. Nothing seems to be making a difference. And I feel like I'm stumbling in the blind not sure why a view would work independently, but not inside a Tab Bar.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that it had everything to do with Translucency and Scroll Bar positioning.

Found an excellent article (which explained the difference and problems I might have been facing) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18798792/explaining-difference-between-automaticallyadjustsscrollviewinsets-extendedlayo)

Onward and upwards to fight another day.

Thanks again to everyone who had suggestions for me.