# Navigation bar blends with black instead of white when presenting a view controller modally

Tags: ios7, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uitoolbar

I'm trying to present a view controller (which is embedded in a navigation controller) modally. The problem is that when the view is presented, it is blending the navigation bar with black rather than white.

I am creating my view controller from a storyboard and showing it by using `-[UIViewController presentViewController:animated:completion:]`.

How can I get the correct blending as can be seen below?

### Incorrect behavior:

[image]

### Correct behavior:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the **Extend Edges** setting had **Under Top Bars** disabled. Once I enabled that setting, everything worked properly.

Note to revert to the defaults, you should enable **Under Top Bars** and **Under Bottom Bars**. The latter is especially useful if you notice the same behavior with a tool bar at the bottom of the view controller.

You can see what the value is set to programmatically by reading the `edgesForExtendedLayout` value on your view controller. If it is set to `UIRectEdgeNone`, you will get the undesirable behavior.

For more information on how extended edges works, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19585104/35690).