# What is edgesForExtendedLayout: for?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Inside one of sample codes from WWDC 14 I've found following line in `init:` in subclass of `UICollectionViewController`:

```
[self setEdgesForExtendedLayout:UIRectEdgeLeft | UIRectEdgeBottom | UIRectEdgeRight];
```

When I had commented it out, it changed nothing. What was the reason to put it there? What is it actually for?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Explaining difference between automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets, extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars, edgesForExtendedLayout in iOS7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18798792/explaining-difference-between-automaticallyadjustsscrollviewinsets-extendedlayo)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'edgesForExtendedLayout' is used to specify which edges of a view should be extended, regardless of bar translucency.

May be you are using this as a view controller which is not embedded in any other view controller or is a root view controller.
You can refer it in apple's official documnetation [here.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIViewController/edgesForExtendedLayout)