# iOS popViewControllerAnimated black bar appear

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar

I have two viewcontrollers.The first viewcontroller has no statusbar.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
        return true
    }

}
```

Also I have set `UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance` to YES in Info.plist.

The second viewcontroller has statusbar.

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

    override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
        return false
    }
}
```

The relationship between them is a push segue.

[image]

The last thing is that I have set translucent property to false in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method.

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    UINavigationBar.appearance().translucent = false
    UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.redColor()

    return true
}
```

When I click back in the navigationbar,there is a black bar.How can I get rid of it?When I set `translucent` to true,the black bar is gone.

[image]

Comment: Seems like it's applications main window background is showing since there a transparent space in your view. Fill that space up with something, and black bar won't be visible anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading the post [Explaining difference between automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets, extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars, edgesForExtendedLayout in iOS7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18798792/explaining-difference-between-automaticallyadjustsscrollviewinsets-extendedlayo),I have figured out a solution.

Set `extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars` to true.

```
func viewDidLoad() {
    extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = true // property introduced in iOS7,default value is false
}
```