# TextViews not in correct position in ScrollView

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uitextview

I have two `UITextView` boxes that are in a `UIView` which is in a `UIScrollView`. My problem is that when I run the app in simulator, the `UITextView` boxes are sitting lower than I would like, but after clicking within a `UITextView` box, then dismissing the keyboard and my `textViewDidEndEditing` function fires off, they set back to the position that I originally wanted them to be in. In my `textViewDidEndEditing` function I did set the `UIScrollView` content offset to go back to (0,0) so my initial solution thought is I need to set the content offset to (0,0) immediately which would then put both of my `UITextView` boxes where I want them.

Now first I tried doing that in `viewDidLoad`, but there was no change, so I then tried setting it in `viewDidAppear`, which worked, but my issue with that is once the view appears, you actually see the textview boxes pop into place, and I do not like that. I also checked my constraints and they are all good, as i thought they might be causing the problem as well. I am not quite sure what I can do to make it work without actually seeing the `UITextView` pop into place when the view appears.

This is what the `UITextView` boxes look like when the view controller first comes up without the viewDidAppear method setting content offset.

[image]

And this is what I want the `UITextView` boxes to look like.

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: If u create it programatically, try create the box in `viewDidLoad` then set their place in `viewDidLayoutSubview`, it should do the trick

Comment: Thank you for the reply. So just to make sure i understand, delete both textview boxes from storyboard and create them in viewDidLoad then set them in viewDidLayoutSubview?

Comment: in `viewDidLoad` set `self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false`

Comment: Sorry, i meant whatever u set in code that related to size and constraint, u should put it in `viewDidLayoutSubview`, it will be same as u set it in `viewDidAppear` but wont be notice by eye, if u already create those boxes with storyboard, then keep it :) in this case is your `scrollview content offset` i guess?

Comment: @Hamza Ansari, that worked perfectly. Thank you very much. Is there a reason why scrollview insets are set automatically by default?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your viewDidLoad set viewController autoScollViewInsets to false:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
}
```

you want more detail about this check this answer:
[Explaining difference between automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets, extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars, edgesForExtendedLayout in iOS7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18798792/explaining-difference-between-automaticallyadjustsscrollviewinsets-extendedlayo)

Comment: Happy to help aCertos