# iOS UITableViewCell overlapping

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm having weird overlapping when i try to reloadData of the tableView, causing the cell's height to change (using `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`), then the content get overlapped with the cell above it, cant figure out how to do it :/

Before:
[image]
[image]

After reload the view from under cell jump to above:
[image]

They are basically the same cell but the top one have that View height = 0 and have no data, And it only happen if the bottom cell is fullscreen (top cell is invisible), if the Revenue per hour cell is visible then this bugs wont appear

Comment: Could it have something to do with `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets` (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/19585104/1305067)

Comment: I don't think this have anything to do with that, its just for tableview overlap navigation bar, my issue is probably from reusing mechanism but i'm not sure what is it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably due to set the same cell identifier, do you refresh cells before reusing them?

```
    - (void)prepareForReuse {    }
```

Implement this method on your table view cell classes. Hope this would be helpful to you.

Comment: what should i do in this function?

Comment: Your cell carries some logics that control the UI for example based on data, it will behave differently. However, because of using the same identifier, the reusable cell get from the recycle array still keeps its old state. "prepareForResuse" called before it will be used, you should refresh it.

Comment: I'm using tableView inside Viewcontroller and this method doesn't seems to exist :/ ...Is it from tableViewcontroller?

Comment: That "prepareForReuse" method belongs to UITableViewCell class :)

Comment: It seems to work but now it breaking some logic that cause the below cell to use the upper cell data, i will try to see what causing it :) thanks