# UITableView inset when parent viewcontroller has a background

Tags: xcode, swift, autolayout

I have a tableviewcontroller that I've added as a child ViewController. Its view is added to a containerview (normal UIView). This works great, and it automatically adjusts the top inset:

[image: TableView with correct top inset]

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.title = "ViewController"
    // self.addBackground()

    // Set up container for the tableview
    self.containerView = UIView()
    self.containerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    self.containerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
    self.view.addSubview(self.containerView)

    let viewDict = ["container": self.containerView]
    self.view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|[container(100)]", options: [], metrics: nil, views: viewDict))
    self.view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|[container]|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: viewDict))

    // Add tableview controller as child
    tableViewController = TableViewController()
    tableViewController.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    self.addChildViewController(tableViewController)
    self.containerView.addSubview(tableViewController.view)
    tableViewController.didMoveToParentViewController(self)

    // Layout
    let tableViewDict = ["child": tableViewController.view]
    self.containerView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|[child]|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: tableViewDict))
    self.containerView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|[child]|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: tableViewDict))
}
```

When I add a background image BEFORE adding the containerview, the first couple of rows are hidden behind the navbar.

```
private func addBackground() {
    let backgroundImage = UIImage(named: "hexley_fork_450")
    let backgroundImageView = UIImageView(image: backgroundImage)
    backgroundImageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    self.view.addSubview(backgroundImageView)

    let viewDict = ["backgroundImageView": backgroundImageView]
    let layouts = [
        "H:[backgroundImageView]|",
        "V:[backgroundImageView]|",
    ]

    for layout in layouts {
        self.view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(layout, options: [], metrics: nil, views: viewDict))
    }
}
```

Result:

[image: TableView with first couple of rows hidden]

Why is this, and how can I prevent it?

Test project on Github: https://github.com/bvankuik/TestBackgroundLayout

Comment: I didn't figure exactly why this happens but you can prevent it by disabling the option "Extend Edges Under Top Bars" on the view controller in the storyboard (in case you use storyboards - or in code otherwise)

Comment: @Ionut You mean adding the line       "tableViewController.edgesForExtendedLayout = .None"? Doesn't seem to fix the problem.

Comment: Not for tableViewController but for you main view controller. Add this in viewDidLoad: edgesForExtendedLayout = .None - just an idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set `self.edgesForExtendedLayout = .None` in `ViewController` instead of `tableViewController.edgesForExtendedLayout` then it works.

because `edgesForExtendedLayout` works for `UIViewController` not a view from the `TableViewController`

you can see the fist image the tableview's greycolor is under the `navigationBar` because the contentview will be under the `navigationBar`,then the tableViewController.view fill the content view

then why the fist works? you can see more detail in [Explaining difference between automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets, extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars, edgesForExtendedLayout in iOS7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18798792/explaining-difference-between-automaticallyadjustsscrollviewinsets-extendedlayo/19585104#19585104)

hope it be helpful :-)

Comment: This is partly a solution. Setting "self.edgesForExtendedLayout = .None" in ViewController indeed works. But now the nice effect of the coloring of the tableview behind the navigationbar has disappeared.

Comment: @BartvanKuik  make an inset of tableview works too : self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(64, 0, 0, 0)

Comment: Yes! That indeed is the best solution for me, and it offers visually the nicest look and feel!