# hide NavigationBar without lifting up the View

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

hiding my NavigationBar with this :

```
func hideAndShow(){

   if self.navigationController?.navigationBar.hidden == true {
        self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: true)

    }else {
        self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: true)
    }
 }
```

but its also lifting up my View (maybe because View is below the Navigation),   how can i hide it without lifting up my View

see the below image for better understanding

[image]

as you can see that my image in my view also get shifted up  while hiding the NavigationBar any idea how can i fix this ??

can we just show the view below the layer of navigation bar ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two steps are required to solve your problem:

1. Add `self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdge.All` to `viewWillAppear`. As a result your view will start at the top of the screen instead of below the NavigationBar. You can read more about `edgesForExtendedLayout` here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19585104/1447641
2. Add a top constraint of {navigationbarheight} to your ImageView.

After that the position of the ImageView shouldn't be effected by the NavigationBar anymore.

Comment: disabling Adjust ScrollView Insets did the job , thanks :) , appreciate you