# View Inside scroll view shifts down

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, xcode8, ios10, ios-autolayout

I am using view inside a scroll view using autolayout , I have set the scrollview constraint as top,bottom,leading and trailing. View inside the scroll view is also set up with same constaint top,bottom,leading and trailing with scrollview. But the view shifts down at runtime.

I am attaching the screen shots.

[image: In bluee color there is scroll view and in gray color it is uiview]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add in the `viewDidLoad()` method:

```
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO
```

Take a look at this answer for a complete and detailed explanation about `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets` and other related `UIScrollView` flags: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19585104/1392452