# Why is the UITableView content offset -20.0?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a table setup like so:

```
view.addSubview(tableView)
tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
    tableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
    tableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
    tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor)
])
```

I log the content offset:

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    print(scrollView.contentOffset.y)
}
```

why is the value `-20.0`? Is it possible to set it to `0.0` ?

Comment: Do you mean bouncing during scroll out of edge? The just disable it `tableView.bounces = false`.

Comment: I guess your tableView seted contentInset.top is 20

Comment: There is a similar question answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48319873/uiscrollview-resting-at-incorrect-contentoffset-20-px-not-0px
It looks like your table view content is going beneath the status bar which height is 20pt or 44pt on iPhones with the notch.